# Pytorch - How differentiate wrt two parameters

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient, tensor, derivative

I am interested in combined derivatives using Pytorch: [image]

In the implemented code below, I have tried, but the code compute two partial derivative (e.g. it computed firstly d'f/d'x and secondly d'f/d'y). Is it possible modify the code in some way that we can compute this derivative with respect two parameters?

```
import torch
def function(x,y):
    f = x**3+y**3
    return f

a =  torch.tensor([4., 5., 6.], requires_grad=True)
b =  torch.tensor([1., 2., 6.], requires_grad=True)
derivative = torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(function, (a,b))
print(derivative)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you duplicate your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68941852/pytorch-combined-derivative-with-respect-two-parameters)?

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the answer. I have deleted the previous one since there was a mistake @Ivan

Comment: What do you refer to as `d'f/d'x`, is it the 1st derivative w.r.t. `x`?

Comment: yes, unfortunately I cannot write the formula directly on stackoverflow @Ivan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [torch.autograd.functional.hessian](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.functional.hessian.html) to get the combined derivatives.

```
>>> f = lambda x, y: (x**3 + y**3).mean()
>>> H = A.hessian(f, (a, b))
```

Since you have two inputs, the result will be a *tuple* containing 2 *tuple*s.

More precisely, you will have

- `H[0][0]` the 2nd derivative w.r.t `x`: `d²z_i/dx_j*dx_j`
- `H[0][1]` the combined derivative w.r.t `x` and `y`: `d²z_i/dx_j*dy_j`
- `H[0][1]` the combined derivative w.r.t `y` and `x`: `d²z_i/dy_j*dx_j`
- `H[1][1]` the 2nd derivative w.r.t `y`: `d²z_i/dy_j*dy_j`

```
>>> H
((tensor([[ 8.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0., 10.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0., 12.]], 
  tensor([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]),
 (tensor([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]))
  tensor([[ 2.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  4.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0., 12.]])
```

---

Indeed if you look at the combined derivative: `d²(x³+y³)/dxdy = d(3x²)/dy = 0`, hence `H[0][1]` and `H[1][0]` are zero matrices.

On the other hand we have `d²x³/d²x = 6x`, since the `f` is averaging the values, it gives `6x/3 = 2x`. Similarly, you get `d²x³/d²y = 6y`.

As a result, you find that `H[0][0] = diag(2a)` and `H[1][1] = diag(2b)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, but this "hessian" work only with a function defined with "lambda"? what about if I have a function that is: "def function(a,b)" like in my example?

Comment: Of course, you can define your function as a `def ...`. Remember you will need to return a single scalar value for `f`.